# magento getting product id based on custom option value

Tags: magento

I need to retrieve an array of cross sell product ids from a product based on a product id retrieved based on a value in a product custom option.

I have researched how to get it using straight MySQL statements. How do I get it using the standard magento calls?

here is the MySQL process:

```
Select option_type_id from mage_catalog_product_option_type_title where option_type_id EQ 'desired value';
```

then:

```
Select option_id from mage_catalog_product_option_type_value where option_type_id EQ option_type_id; (from above step)
```

then:

```
Select product_id from mage_catalog_product_option where option_id EQ option id; (from previous step)
```

then:

```
Select linked_product_id from mage_catalog_product_link where product_id EQ product_id (from previous step) AND link_type_id ='5';
```

(I'm experienced in PHP/MySQL but barely past novice level in Magento)

Can anyone help? Thank you very, very much!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('option_type_id','desired value’);
$collection->join(array('option' => 'catalog/product_option'), 'main_table.product_id = option.product_id')
           ->join(array('option_value' => 'catalog/product_option_type_value'), 'option.option_id = option_value.option_id');
var_dump($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
```

And this is how it generally works:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('option_type_id','desired value’);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('option_id',$collection->getFirstItem()->getOptionId());
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$collection->getFirstItem()->getProductId());
var_dump($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
```